# How to open VLC in fullscreen mode in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fullscreen, vlc

Im using MobileVLCKit, here is my code:

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController,VLCMediaPlayerDelegate{

  var mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mediaPlayer.delegate = self
    let url = NSURL(string: "URL HERE")
    mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(URL: url!)
  }
}
```

I want to open VLC in fullscreen with play,pause and timer

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, Have you managed to play video in full screen mode?

Comment: same problem here, do you have solution?

Answer (score 0):

VLCKit does not include a "fullscreen" feature. You need to set the mediaPlayer's drawable to a UIView and take care of the view handling yourself.

Answer (score 0):

*I found a sollution from [Videolan/VLC Kit](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/)

First we've to install VLC pods

```
pod 'MobileVLCKit'
```

```
var mediaPlayer: VLCMediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()
```

```
 func playDownload(url: URL)
 {
        self.movieView = UIView()
        self.movieView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.movieView.frame = UIScreen.screens[0].bounds

        //Add tap gesture to movieView for play/pause
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.movieViewTapped(_:)))
        self.movieView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        //Add movieView to view controller
        self.view.addSubview(self.movieView)
        let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
        mediaPlayer.media = media
        mediaPlayer.delegate = self
        mediaPlayer.drawable = movieView
        mediaPlayer.play()
 }
```

```
@objc func movieViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if mediaPlayer.isPlaying 
    {
      mediaPlayer.pause()
      let remaining = mediaPlayer.remainingTime
      let time = mediaPlayer.time
      print("Paused at \(time?.stringValue ?? "nil") with \(remaining?.stringValue ?? "nil") time remaining")
    } else {
      mediaPlayer.play()
      print("Playing")
    }
}
```