# MobileVLCKit video full screen

Tags: ios, swift, vlc

I want to play video streaming using MobileVLCKit in fullscreen mode.
How can I do this?
Please share code if possible (swift)..

Comment: Duplication of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37445172/2041996

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that my previous answer on the old thread was massively downvoted back then. It's still true though. MVK renders in a simple UIView, so it is the obligation of the client app to implement the view handling, be it a tiny one or one filling the screen.

Note that there is sample code available on how to integrate MVK here: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/